# Problemas com sockets em java , como enviar e receber mensagens simultaneamente entre cliente e servidor?

Tags: java, socket, stream, redes

Estou trabalhando com sockets em java e consegui me deparar com o seguinte problema, escrevendo a classe servidor mandei uma mensagem para o cliente ler, até aí tudo,ok!! Mas quando eu tento mandar do cliente  uma mensagem para o servidor não consigo, ter as duas mensagens serem lidas dos dois lados simultaneamente!

Qual o problema dessas classes?

```
public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream())) {
            System.out.println("Cliente : -- Qual a  mensagem?\n" + scanner.nextLine());
        }

        socket.getOutputStream().write("This is ridiculous!!".getBytes());
        socket.getOutputStream().flush();
    }
}
```

E na classe Servidor:

```
public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5000);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

            try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                w.println("Servidor: Java é uma boa linguagem!");
            }
            while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(entrada.nextLine());
            }

        }
     }
 }
```

O que devo fazer? Já tentei de tudo , mas não consegui que o servidor escreva  e leia  uma mensagem do cliente e também que o cliente leia e escreva uma mensagem para o servidor, nessa mesma ordem respectivamente!
 Tudo de uma só vez é possível?

A saida da classe Cliente é a seguinte:

```
Cliente : -- Qual a  mensagem?
Servidor: Java é uma boa linguagem!
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:943)
    at aula.ari.teste3.Cliente.main(Cliente.java:21)
```

Comment: Qual é a linha 21?

Answer (score 3):

Minha linguagem principal não é Java, portanto vou tentar te ajudar

Pelo que consegui interpretar o seu código do servidor mata a conexão com o cliente assim que é enviada a primeira mensagem ("Servidor: Java é uma boa linguagem!") considerando que entrada.hasNextLine() é falso em um primeiro momento, logo o loop infinito é executado novamente, aceitando nova conexão e matando a existente devido a perda de escopo da conexão.

É necessário manipular a sua conexão enquanto ela estiver ativa e responder assim que uma nova mensagem for recebida, o que não é o caso do seu código.

Já no código cliente você aparentemente tentou enviar uma mensagem antes de receber algo do servidor, portanto é necessário rever a ordem desta implementação para obter o resultado desejado. Somente após feitos estes ajustes você poderá interpretar o que foi recebido entre as conexões e então responder adequadamente.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Com a criação de uma socket você está praticamente implementando seu próprio protocolo, então seria legal você definir uma maneira de fechar esta conexão através do cliente (por exemplo o padrão do http é "\n\n" ao final da string, caso o keep_alive não esteja ativo) e detectar através dela o fechamento, evitando que a conexão seja fechada previamente pelo servidor. Além disso também deve haver algum controle para caso a conexão seja fechada inadequadamente (por exemplo uma queda de conexão).

Answer (score 1):

Isso está acontecendo porque sua porta está fechada no momento em que o cliente tenta realizar esse procedimento.

Tem um [tutorial bem bacana na Caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/apendice-sockets/#19-11-solucao-do-sistema-de-chat) que pode te ajudar, ele tem um exemplo de Chat, que acredito que seja mais ou menos o que você quer: [link](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/apendice-sockets/#19-11-solucao-do-sistema-de-chat).

**Sobre a segurança nesse procedimento**

Cuidado com a implementação desse procedimento, ela dá uma certa liberdade a pessoas maliciosas. Na hora de implementar segurança você pode ter uma certa dificuldade. Evite enviar dados críticos (usuário e senha, por exemplo), não aceite qualquer tipo de dado e também defina quem poderá utilizar essa porta, definindo os clientes a dedo.

É um **conhecimento bastante válido** aprender sobre sockets, mas deve ser utilizado com cautela, *não basta apenas copiar código da internet*. Além disso, você pode ter dificuldade para implementar uma camada de segurança.

Recomendo também que você veja um pouco sobre [WebSockets](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) caso sua aplicação seja web e [SSL](http://www.comodobr.com/ssl_o_que_e.php). Caso seja Desktop, tente [criptografar com AES](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) tanto nas informações que vão para o servidor quanto nas que retornam. Não é a forma mais simples de implementar, mas já dificulta a vida do invasor uma vez que ele precisará das chaves.

Lembrando sempre que aplicações java JAR são facilmente descompiláveis, então a pessoa que tiver acesso ao JAR terá acesso à chave e consequentemente aos dados.

Comment: @AndersonBMagalhães Obrigado amigo , suas informações são de grande valia , e  futuramente quero me aprofundar no conhecimento de todos eles,quanto ao link da caelum o  material é bom mesmo, mas nesse casso não quero fazer um chat, quero resolver essa parte de logica da aplicação e faze- las rodar sem problemas!!